# For what pair of positive integers $\left(A, B\right)$ is $2016^A + 2000^B$ is a perfect cube?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

This problem is from a textbook in our school:

For what pair of positive integers $\left(A, B\right)$ is $2016^A + 2000^B$ is a perfect cube?

I tried to find the pair of positive integers using brute force, but I didn’t succeed.

I don’t have any idea to solve this problem. Can someone help me to solve this problem?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: This was asked here recently already. For a similar type of question, see also [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3561182/prove-that-there-are-no-integer-solutions-to-c2-2018a-2018b?noredirect=1). See also [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/45926/non-negative-solutions-of-the-equation-5n7m-k3?noredirect=1) for $5^a+7^b=c^3$. Try this method for $2016^a+2000^b=c^3$.

Comment: online wolfram alpha says no solutions in integers. https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i2d=true&i=solve+integers+Power%5B2016%2Ca%5D%2BPower%5B2000%2Cb%5D%3DPower%5Bc%2C3%5D

Comment: Could you please relate the author and title of the "textbook in our school" that you cite in your question? Thanks.

Comment: @Servaes you're right, it should have been $2^{4A}(126^A+2^C 125^B)$ if $A > B$ and $4A-4B=C$, or $2^{4B}(2^{C}126^A+125^B)$ if $B > A$ and $4B-4A=C$

Comment: OP likes to ask these questions, and then delete them. https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4671862/are-there-any-integer-solutions-to-2002a-2009b-x7 and https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4689888/find-all-pairs-of-positive-integers-a-b-such-that-2007a2009b-c5 and https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4681327/prove-that-325-3225-32225-is-not-a-perfect-square

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are no solutions.

*Proof* :

Suppose that there are positive integers $A,B,C$ such that $2016^A+2000^B=C^3$.

Since $2016\equiv 0\pmod 9$ and $2000\equiv 2\pmod 9$, we have $2^B\equiv C^3\pmod 9$.

Suppose that $B\equiv 1\pmod 3$. Then, letting $B=3D+1$, we have $2^{B}\equiv 2^{3D+1}\equiv 2(-1)^D\equiv \pm 2\pmod 9$, but there is no $C$ such that $C^3\equiv \pm 2\pmod 9$.

Suppose that $B\equiv 2\pmod 3$. Then, letting $B=3D+2$, we have $2^B\equiv 2^{3D+2}\equiv 4(-1)^D\equiv \pm 4\pmod 9$, but there is no $C$ such that $C^3\equiv \pm 4\pmod 9$.

It follows that $B\equiv 0\pmod 3$. So, let $B=3D$.

Letting $E=2000^D$, we have $2016^A=C^3-E^3$, i.e.
$$2^{5A}\cdot 3^{2A}\cdot 7^A=(C-E)(C^2+CE+E^2)$$

- Suppose that $7\mid C-E$ and $7\mid C^2+CE+E^2$. Then, since $C\equiv E\pmod 7$, we have $0\equiv C^2+CE+E^2\equiv 3E^2\pmod 7$. This implies $7\mid E$ which is impossible.
- Suppose that $9\mid C-E$ and $9\mid C^2+CE+E^2$. Then, since $C\equiv E\pmod 9$, we have $0\equiv C^2+CE+E^2\equiv 3E^2\pmod 9$. This implies $3\mid E$ which is impossible.
- It follows from $C^2+CE+E^2=(C-E)^2+3E(C-E)+3E^2$ that $3\mid C-E\iff 3\mid C^2+CE+E^2$.

From these, we have three cases to consider :

- Case 1 : $(C-E,C^2+CE+E^2)=(2^a3^17^F,2^b3^{2A-1}7^G)$ where $(F,G)=(A,0)$ or $(0,A)$
- Case 2 : $(C-E,C^2+CE+E^2)=(2^a3^{2A-1}7^A,2^b3^1)$
- Case 3 : $(C-E,C^2+CE+E^2)=(2^a3^{2A-1},2^b3^17^A)$

where $a,b$ are positive integers satisfying $a+b=5A$. ($a,b$ are positive since $C,E$ are even.)

---

Case 1 : $(C-E,C^2+CE+E^2)=(2^a3^17^F,2^b3^{2A-1}7^G)$ where $(F,G)=(A,0)$ or $(0,A)$

Eliminating $C$ and dividing by $3$, we have
$$E^2=2^b3^{2A-2}7^G-\underbrace{3(2^{2a}7^{2F}+2^a7^FE)}_{\text{divisible by $3$}}$$
Suppose that $2A-2\geqslant 1$. Then, $3\mid E^2$ which is impossible. So, we have to have $2A-2\lt 1$, i.e. $A=1$ to have
$$2^b7^G-E^2=2^{2a}3^17^{2F}+2^a3^17^FE$$
Since $a+b=5$, we have $\text{LHS}\leqslant 2^47^1-2000^{2}\lt 0$ while RHS is positive, a contradiction.

---

Case 2 : $(C-E,C^2+CE+E^2)=(2^a3^{2A-1}7^A,2^b3^1)$

Eliminating $C$ and dividing by $3$, we get
$$2^b-2^{2a}3^{4A-3}7^{2A}=2^{a}3^{2A-1}7^AE+E^2$$

Since $b=5A-a\leqslant 5A-1$, we have
$$\text{LHS}\leqslant 2^{5A-1}-2^23^{4A-3}7^{2A}=2^{5A-1}\bigg(1-\frac{8}{27}\bigg(\frac{3969}{32}\bigg)^A\bigg)\lt 0$$
while RHS is positive, a contradiction.

---

Case 3 : $(C-E,C^2+CE+E^2)=(2^a3^{2A-1},2^b3^17^A)$

Eliminating $C$ and dividing by $3$, we get
$$2^b7^A=2^{2a}3^{4A-3}+2^{4D+a}3^{2A-1}5^{3D}+2^{8D}5^{6D}$$

Suppose that $a\not=4D$. Then, $2^{2a}, 2^{4D+a},2^{8D}$ are distinct. Dividing the both sides by $\min(2^{2a},2^{4D+a},2^{8D})$, RHS is odd. So, we have to have $2^b=\min(2^{2a},2^{4D+a},2^{8D})$. Next, let us consider
$$2^b7^A-2^{2a}3^{4A-3}=2^{4D+a}3^{2A-1}5^{3D}+2^{8D}5^{6D}$$
where
$$\text{LHS}\leqslant 2^{2a}7^A-2^{2a}3^{4A-3}=\frac{2^{2a}7^A}{27}\underbrace{\bigg(27-\bigg(\frac{81}{7}\bigg)^A\bigg)}_{\text{negative if $A\geqslant 2$}}$$ while RHS is positive. So, it follows from $A=1$ that
$$2^b7^1-2^{8D}5^{6D}=2^{2a}3^1+2^{4D+a}3^15^{3D}$$
where $\text{LHS}\leqslant 2^{8D}7^1-2^{8D}5^{6}=2^{8D}(7-5^{6})\lt 0$ while RHS is positive, a contradiction.

Therefore, we have $a=4D$ and so

$$2^b7^A=2^{8D}\underbrace{(3^{4A-3}+3^{2A-1}5^{3D}+5^{6D})}_{\text{odd}}$$
which implies $b=8D$, and dividing the both sides by $2^b$, we have
$$\frac{7^A}{27}\underbrace{\bigg(27-\bigg(\frac{81}{7}\bigg)^A\bigg)}_{\text{negative if $A\geqslant 2$}}=3^{2A-1}5^{3D}+5^{6D}$$
So, we have to have $A=1$. From $a+b=5A$, we have $12D=5$ which is impossible.$\quad\blacksquare$

Comment: That's a lot of work for a question (allegedly) from a textbook.